# SVG and other picture format like PNG/JPEG support solution

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

As `SVG` format is not supported by flutter. I'm forced to use [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package which doesn't support `.png`.

So I'm looking for a solution which supports both `SVG` and other picture formats like `.png`,`.jpg` etc.

PS: the network url is mapped like `example.com/media/id` so there's no extention in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sample following methods

```js
     Widget getPicture(String url) {
var mimeType = getFileExtension(url);
if (mimeType == "svg") {
  return SvgPicture.asset(
      assetName,
      color: Colors.red,
      semanticsLabel: 'A red up arrow'
  );
}
else {
  return NetworkImage(...)
}
  }
```

```js
String getFileExtension(String fileName) {
 return "." + fileName.split('.').last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but there is no extention in the url.